# Is it possible to duplicate images in LittleSnapper?

Tags: applications

The reason is that I have some screenshots of full websites. Though for inspiration and illustration reasons I need to crop them to show different parts of that website. I know that when you crop an image in LittleSnapper it does not damage the original but I really would like to be able to see the full image AND the cropped version

So that is why I need to know if there is a way to make copies of the image. Of course there is always a long way of doing it; such as drag it to the desktop and drag it back in, or go back to the web page. But does the application have a copy and paste (images) feature

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LittleSnapper keeps it's images in special library file, so the only way to copy images is to do the long way that you described.

I'd recommend you get on the LittleSnapper discussion board over at RealMac to add your voice to the group of users who'd also like to get at their images in a more flexible way.

http://support.realmacsoftware.com/discussions/littlesnapper/

Comment: Thanks a lot I will participate in those discussions. - By the way I just noticed the library file today - so are ALL the images stored in that single file "username.lslibrary"

Comment: That's right. From an architectural point of view, it was a bad decision, and it definitely won't be something they can fix quickly/easily, so they will be resistant without a lot of users asking for a change. It may turn out that the .lslibrary is in a known (ie. non-proprietory) format, such as a coredata table, or some other third party format, in which case it would be possible to pull all the images out and process them normally. If they've made their own format you'll have to wait on them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily by using Windows Painter. Just go to your desired page, click "Print Screen", then open Windows Paint and paste onto it. After that, crop as you need.

Keep in mind, coping images or webpages may be subject of copyright.

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing Apple's OS X and Windows? I believe the OP is referring to OS X software.